# Formatting mongo query

Tags: mongodb, php-5.6

I have following code:

```
$group = [];
$comparison = '=';
$group = array('$and'=>array());
$filters = ['abc', 'xyz'];

foreach ($filters as $filter) {
  $group['$and'][] = array(
  'team_id' => array (
    ($comparison == '=' ? '$nin' : '$in') => array($filter)
   )
 ); 
}
echo json_encode($group, true);
```

i have tried few things like $group['$and'][]['team_id'][$comparison] = $filter; in foreach loop but no luck

this produces following:

```
{  
   "$and":[  
      {  
         "team_id":{  
            "$nin":[  
               "abc"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "team_id":{  
            "$nin":[  
               "xyz"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to get:

```
"$and":[  
            {  
               "team_id":{  
                  "$nin":[  
                     "abc",
                     "xyz"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
```

Comment: What do you need the `foreach`  for?  Why you don't remove it and the other line just by `($comparison == '=' ? '$nin' : '$in') => $filters`?

Comment: @f-CJ foreach loop is in a bigger schema of things, unfortunately  I cannot change it :( i know your change will work but it will not work in this case.

Comment: What's your question then? If you cannot change the code you need to learn how to live with it.